# In TableView, the whole table can't click anymore after the sentence " cell.selected = true "

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

`cell.selected = true`

After this line, I can't select rows any more.
Is there anybody who can help me?
Thanks

```
@IBAction func SelectAll(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if(selectAll == true)
        {


            var i = 0 as Int
            while(i < indexArray.count){
                //indexArray[i] = true



                let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
                self.tableView(self.selectDownloadTableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect);

                println(rowToSelect)

                i = i+1
            }

            selectAll = false

            creeLigueBouton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UnSelect", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "creerButtonMethod")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [creeLigueBouton]
        }

        else{
            var i = 0 as Int
            while(i < indexArray.count){
                //indexArray[i] = true



                let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
                self.tableView(self.selectDownloadTableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect);

                println(rowToSelect)

                i = i+1
            }
            selectAll = true

            creeLigueBouton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "creerButtonMethod")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [creeLigueBouton]
        }
    }

    func creerButtonMethod() {
       SelectAll(self)
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    {
        selectDownloadTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        indexArray[indexPath.row] = true
        println("in did select row ")
        println(indexPath.row)

        var cell : UITableViewCell = self.selectDownloadTableView .cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue;
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        **cell.selected = true**
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post some code in order to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: I just edited the post. Thanks for interesting to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can deselect your cell after you've selected it with `deselectRowAtIndexPath`. In your case it would be:

```
selectDownloadTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
```

Or you could just reload the table with `selectDownloadTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea. Problem solved now. Really Thank!! :)